# Getting Result from Cancelled Task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a program, roughly like the example below.
A task is gathering a number of values and returning them to a caller.
Sometimes the tasks may get cancelled.
In those cases, I still want to get the results the tasks have gathered so far.
Hence I catch the `CancelledError` exception, clean up, and return the completed results.

```
async def f():
    results = []
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            res = await slow_call()
            results.append(res)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            results.append('Undecided')
    return results

def on_done(task):
    if task.cancelled():
        print('Incomplete result', task.result()
    else:
        print(task.result())

async def run():
    task = asyncio.create_task(f())
    task.add_done_callback(on_done)
```

The problem is that the value returned after a task is cancelled doesn't appear to be available in the task.
Calling `task.result()` simply rethrows `CancelledError`. Calling `task._result` is just `None`.

Is there a way to get the return value of a cancelled task, assuming it has one?

**Edit:** I realize now that catching the `CancelledError` results in the task not being cancelled at all.
This leaves me with another conundrum: How do I signal to the tasks owner that this result is only a "half" result, and the task has really been cancelled.
I suppose I could add an extra return value indicating this, but that seems to go against the whole idea of the task cancellation system.

Any suggestions for a good approach here?

Comment: pretty sure the `task` being cancelled will also cause the future to be cancelled.  this will always cause the future to raise a `CancelledError`, independent of whether the task "failed" or not.  maybe the task could "return" values by pushing them into a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-queue.html)?

Comment: @SamMason I did consider just using queues for everything. It just seems to go against the idea of tasks and having `result()`s in the first place.

Comment: it depends what API you're after.  generally people care about tasks doing a single well defined "task", but here yours is doing many things and partial results are useful.  hence, in this case, using a queue seems more appropriate.  note that you could also just pass a `list` to `f` and have it append results to it.  you'd need some way of getting this list to `on_done`.  a queue would let you get intermediate results as they were added rather than just waiting until the task "finished", it all depends on what abstraction is more appropriate!

Comment: how come you're using `add_done_callback` rather than just `await`ing the task?  one of the biggest advantages of `asyncio` is getting rid of the "callback hell" that existed before, e.g. in twisted python.

Comment: @SamMason this is because I have many tasks. I was trying to use `asyncio.wait()`, but I want it to return on _either_ a task completing or throwing an error. It seems that currently, you have to choose which condition to wait for, so I had to use `on_done` :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm a long way away from understanding the use case, but the following does something sensible for me:

```
import asyncio

async def fn(results):
    for i in range(10):
        # your slow_call
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        results.append(i)

def on_done(task, results):
    if task.cancelled():
        print('incomplete', results)
    else:
        print('complete', results)

async def run():
    results = []
    task = asyncio.create_task(fn(results))
    task.add_done_callback(lambda t: on_done(t, results))
    # give fn some time to finish, reducing this will cause the task to be cancelled
    # you'll see the incomplete message if this is < 1.1
    await asyncio.sleep(1.1)

asyncio.run(run())
```

it's the use of `add_done_callback` and `sleep` in `run` that feels very awkward and makes me think I don't understand what you're doing.  maybe posting something to https://codereview.stackexchange.com containing more of the calling code would help get ideas of better ways to structure things.  note that there are other libraries like [trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io) that provide much nicer interfaces to Python coroutines than the `asyncio` builtin library (which was standardised prematurely IMO)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, because in my opinion, collides with the meaning of cancellation of a task.
You can implements a similar behavior inside your slow_call, by triggering the CancelledError, catching it inside your function and then returns whatever you want.

Comment: Well, I am catching it and returning whatever I want. The problem is that the value I return is getting thrown away.